# How do I only select non-empty cells in function?

Tags: google-sheets

I use this function to find a random content of a cell:

```
=index(A3:A100, randbetween(1, counta(A3:A100) ) )
```

Some of the cells in `A` are empty. How can I change this function so that only those cells  considered are not empty?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't. You should have an auxiliary column with all values, no blanks, and run it over it.